# When hexdump is used with a -x option, are the bytes to the right of each group low addresses?

Tags: hexdump

When I use hexdump directly, the output is in the form of two-byte sets, but when I use the -C option, I find that the output order has changed.

```
$hexdump -x a.out
0000000 652f 6374 702f 7361 7773 0a64
$hexdump -C a.out
0000000 2f 65 74 63 2f 70 61 73  73 77 64 0a  ....
```

My assumption is that the address of 2f is 0000000, the address of 65 is 0000001, and the address of 74 is 0000002... Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

- `-x` will display the data big-endian (assume it's a two byte object and reverse them at least on my little-endian host)

  ```
  $ echo -n "ab" | hexdump -x | head -1
  0000000    6261
  ```
- `-C` will dump the data as is:

  ```
  $ echo -n "ab" | hexdump -C | head -1
  00000000  61 62                                             |ab|
  ```